# Assign values to matrix with index of other data frame

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, assign

My dataframe, `D` is like this.

`D$fit` has both distance (0:6) and dg (1:3) info

```
D <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
   distance  dg fit
1         0   1 A
2         1   1 B
3         2   1 C
4         3   1 D
5         4   1 E
6         5   1 F
7         6   1 G
8         0   2 H
9         1   2 I
10        2   2 J
11        3   2 K
12        4   2 L
13        5   2 M
14        0   3 O
15        1   3 P
16        2   3 Q
17        3   3 R
")
```

I want to assign fit values to this matrix, `md`, corresponding to distance and dg.

```
md <- matrix(1:21, nrow = 7)
colnames(md) <- c(1:3)
rownames(md) <- c(0:6)
md[] <- NA

   1  2  3
0 NA NA NA
1 NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA
```

I've tried but failed with this code

```
cmd = expand.grid(i=seq(0,6), j = seq(1,3))
i <- seq(0,6)
j <- seq(1,3)
md[i,j] <-  D$fit[D$distance == cmd[1] & D$dg == cmd[2]]
```

Comment: I don't think you need to fill a table - you could just do it in one go - `with(D, tapply(fit, list(distance,dg), FUN=as.character) )`

Comment: Yes! It works.. Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `acast` from `library(reshape2)`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(D, distance~dg, value.var="fit")
```

---

Or with `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(D, idvar="distance", timevar="dg", direction="wide")
```